# Internet Connection failure

Tags: 15.04

I recently installed version 15.04 and now have 2 issues.
1. On start-up my PC connects to my WiFi but loses that connection after a short period of time. I then have to shut down the PC and re-start to access the WiFi.
2. I cannot access the Akonadi service. Hence KAddressBook and KOrganiser do not work.
**Please** advise how I may rectify these issues.

Comment: Have you tried disconnecting and reconnecting manually? I get that issue on occasion to. If that doesn't work, try running `sudo service network-manager restart` and seeing if that helps any.

Comment: Thank you. Have tried manual reconnection, rebooting, switching off and on in the various control panels etc. I can reconnect for a short period of time and then connection fails again. I will try sudo service etc if I can keep the connection for long enough.

Comment: No, you'll want to run that command *when* you disconnect, not while.

Comment: Thank you again RPi Awesomeness. Using the sudo command helps. Still losing the connection but less frequently. Will search for a permanent solution to this issue to get back to the pre- 15.04 situation! Will get back to you if I succeed.